# jquery - after jquery function finishes do things

Tags: jquery

How can I make to do something after this line finishes:

```
$("#token").val(rep.token)
```

Basically I have a hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" id="token" value=""/>
```

When it finishes inserting the value into the input I want to start doing something else.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Yes, add your other lines of code right after the one you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, changing the value of inputs are instantaneous. But still, to be sure, you can attach this to a [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event. You can do something for **this particular** event:

```
$("#token").val(rep.token).change(function(){
  if ($("#token").val() == rep.token)
    // do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **[.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)** event:

```
$("#token").val(rep.token).change(function(){
    // Your code here
});
```